# Как правильно использовать: Futures, Streams и Async/Await во Flutter?

Tags: async-await, flutter, dart

дорогие разработчики. Уже на протяжение нескольких дней не могу понять  как правильно использовать: Futures, Streams и Async/Await. Я просмотрел видео на официальном канале, но в итоге ничего не смог понять. Было бы круто, если кто-то смог мне это объяснить. Потому что я часто задаю вопросы с использованием этих классов и функций, но не понимаю как они работают. Спасибо за понимание))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Длительные задачи распространены в мобильных приложениях. В Flutter/Dart это решается с помощью Future. Future позволяет вам выполнять работу асинхронно (Async/Await), чтобы освободить любые другие потоки (Streams), которые не должны быть заблокированы. Например: поток пользовательского интерфейса (UI).
Что важно:

- Код в Dart работает в одном треде (прим. thread — поток) выполнения.
- Из-за кода, который долго занимает (блокирует) тред выполнения,
  программа может зависнуть.
- Объекты Future (futures) представляют результаты асинхронных операций
  — обработки или ввода-вывода, которые будут завершены позже.
- Чтобы приостановить выполнение до завершения в будущем, используйте
  await в асинхронной функции (или then() при использовании Future
  API).
- Чтобы поймать ошибки, используйте в асинхронной функции конструкцию
  try-catch (или catchError() при использовании Future API).

---

### [Async/Await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await)

[image: Async/Await]

Асинхронное программирование - это форма параллельного выполнения, которая ускоряет цепочку событий в цикле программирования. Однако вы не можем использовать асинхронное программирование во всех случаях. Это работает только в тех случаях, когда вы ищете простоту, а не эффективность. Для обработки простых и независимых данных асинхронное программирование является отличным выбором.

**Пример:**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  var response = await http.get('http://google.com'); 
  ... // Наш поток не будет заблокирован, можно выполнять другой код...
  print(response.body); // Как только мы получим ответ мы его отобразим
}
```

---

### [Future](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#what-is-a-future)

Future представляет собой результат асинхронной операции и может иметь два состояния: незавершенное или завершенное. Так как асинхронные операции могут возвращать исключения, их необходимо обрабатывать. Для этого мы можем использовать следующие методы:

- [Future.then](https://flutter-academy.com/async-in-flutter-futures/#code-classlanguage-textfuturethencode)
- [Future.catchError](https://flutter-academy.com/async-in-flutter-futures/#code-classlanguage-textfuturecatcherrorcode)
- [Future.whenComplete](https://flutter-academy.com/async-in-flutter-futures/#code-classlanguage-textfuturewhencompletecode)
- [Future.timeout](https://flutter-academy.com/async-in-flutter-futures/#code-classlanguage-textfuturetimeoutcode)

**Пример:**

```
import 'dart:async';

const news = '<gathered news goes here>';
const moreSecond = Duration(seconds: 120);

Future<void> printDailyNewsDigest() => gatherNewsReports().then(print).catchError(handleError); // Запрашиваем новости, если они приходят отображаем их, если нет обрабатываем ошибку

Future<String> gatherNewsReports() => Future.delayed(moreSecond, () => news); // Получаем новости через 2 минуты (Например через API)

main() {
  printDailyNewsDigest(); // асинхронный метод
  printWinningLotteryNumbers(); // синхронный метод
  printWeatherForecast(); // синхронный метод
  printBaseballScore(); // синхронный метод
}

printWinningLotteryNumbers() {
  print('Winning lotto numbers: [23, 63, 87, 26, 2]');
}

printWeatherForecast() {
  print("Tomorrow's forecast: 70F, sunny.");
}

printBaseballScore() {
  print('Baseball score: Red Sox 10, Yankees 0');
}
```

**Вывод программы:**

```
Winning lotto numbers: [23, 63, 87, 26, 2] 
Tomorrow's forecast: 70F,sunny. 
Baseball score: Red Sox 10, Yankees 0 
<gathered news goes here>
```

---

### [Streams](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)

[image: Stream]

Stream - это последовательность асинхронных событий. Это похоже на асинхронный итерируемый объект (Iterable) - где вместо получения следующего события, когда вы запрашиваете его. Stream сообщает вам, что есть событие, когда он будет готов.
Существует два типа потоков: потоки-подписки (single subscription) и широковещательные (broadcast).

Данные метод берет свои корни из реактивного программирования (ReactiveX), и достаточно сложна в изучении новичкам. Если по простому, все что попадет в поток данных, и будет изменяться внутри него, также мгновенно будет изменяться и в других местах где оно используется. Чтобы больше разобраться с этой темой рекомендую прочитать [данную статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/450950/).

**Пример:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CounterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterPageState createState() => _CounterPageState();
}

class _CounterPageState extends State<CounterPage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  final StreamController<int> _streamController = StreamController<int>(); // Наш поток

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _streamController.close(); // Закрываем поток
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Stream version of the Counter App')),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<int>(
          stream: _streamController.stream, // Создаем и открываем поток
          initialData: _counter, // Наши данные из потока
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot){
            return Text('You hit me: ${snapshot.data} times'); // С помощью StreamBuilder получаем асинхронно данные из потока
          }
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: (){
          _streamController.sink.add(++_counter); // Изменяем данные в потоке (+1)
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

### UPD:

[Поподробнее можно посмотреть на видео.](https://youtu.be/cvioU1c5hNY)

Comment: Вот только не смешивайте конкуррентность и параллелизм. Future - это про конкуррентность, выполнение в том же потоке. Isolates - про параллелизм и выполнение в других потоках https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html

Comment: @VAndrJ да вы правы. Если найдете ещё недочеты, добавьте их пожалуйста.