# Как реализована многопоточность в Dart?

Tags: многопоточность, dart

Дорогие разработчики, не могли бы вы мне объяснить **как работать с потоками в Dart ?** Вот в C# (в пространстве имен) System.Threading, есть класс **Thread** представляющий отдельный поток, он вообще определяет множество методов и свойств, которые позволяют управлять потоком и получать информацию о нем и прочее прочее, а как с этим делом обстоит в Dart ?
Большое спасибо !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Dart has a single thread, or event-loop, of execution.](https://medium.com/hackernoon/are-futures-in-dart-threads-2cdc5bd8063a)

Из цитаты выше можно понять что Dart однопоточен, но я думаю для ваших задач хватит асинхронные методы, такие как: [Futures, Streams, Async/Await](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1013829/261617) и [Isolates](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html). Так-же есть библиотека [threading](https://pub.dev/packages/threading) эмулирующая работу System.Threading из C#.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ ! Хотел уточнить у вас, что бы до меня "дошло" наконец-то: 
 - то есть многопоточность как в C# где можно создать кучу потоков самостоятельно, Dart не поддерживает ?

Comment: Да, не поддерживает. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Огромное, просто нереально большое спасибо вам !

Comment: [Ещё возможно пригодиться mutex](https://pub.dev/packages/mutex)

Comment: Отлично, сейчас посмотрю ! Я просто готов вам купить кофе :)

Comment: За ссылку библиотеки threading очень благодарен !
Вы мне очень помогли разобраться в этом вопросе ...

Comment: @Northwood_FX не за что, будут вопросы задавайте)