# Future methods dart

Tags: async-await, асинхронность, flutter, dart, future

как дождаться выполнение асинхронного метода dart?

Answer (score 3):

Пример 1, работает асинхронно:

```
Future<void> fetchUserOrder() {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => print('Large Latte'));
}

void main() {
  fetchUserOrder();
  print('Fetching user order...');
}

// Console:  
// Fetching user order...
// Large Latte
```

Пример 2, работает асинхронно-синхронно:

```
Future<void> fetchUserOrder() {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => print('Large Latte'));
}

void main() {
  fetchUserOrder().then((v){
    print('Fetching user order...');
  });
}

// Console:
// Large Latte
// Fetching user order...
```

А еще есть виджет для работы с [Future](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future-class.html), [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

---

[Как правильно использовать: Futures, Streams и Async/Await во Flutter?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013673/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-futures-streams-%D0%B8-async-await-%D0%B2%D0%BE-flutter)

[Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Answer (score 1):

Короче как я понял этого сделать нельзя но если у вас есть какой то код который зависит от этого, то лучше сделать проверку. Например у меня был list которой использовался в переопрeделeнном методе

```
Widget build(){
    list = getList();
    return new Scaffold();
    }
```

Решение:

```
void setListInfo() async{
list = getList();
}
Widget build(){
if(await setListInfo()){
return new Scaffold(body: Text("Список создан"));
}else{
return new Scaffold(body: Text("Список не создан"));
}
}
```

Comment: Плохо, поняли... Вы сами указали Future в заголовке, но не поняли что это такое.