# Где разместить функцию для заполнения данными из таблицы?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

Где разместить функцию для заполнения данными из таблицы? Определение функции

```
/*ФУНКЦИЯ ЗАПОЛНЯЕТ КОЛЛЕКЦИЮ ДАННЫМИ ИЗ ТАБЛИЦЫ*/
 Future<void> _funGetData() async {
  var list = await _database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Person');
  //заполняем коллекцию объектами
  _ara = List<Person>.from( list.map((e) => Person.fromMap(e)) );
 }
```

Вызов функции

```
//ГДЕ НУЖНО РАЗМЕСТИТЬ ЭТУ ФУНКЦИЮ ???
_funGetData();
```

В моем примере функция распологается после создания или инициализации базы данных, после проверки. **ГДЕ ЕЕ НУЖНО РАЗМЕСТИТЬ ПРАВИЛЬНО???**

```
if(_database.isOpen) {
   _funTableCreate(_tablePerson);
   //ГДЕ НУЖНО РАЗМЕСТИТЬ ЭТУ ФУНКЦИЮ ???
   _funGetData();
  }
```

В первом варианте, при запуске приложения ОЧЕНЬ БЫСТРО появляется красное окно с ошибкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Затем появляется вывод данных из таблицы. Очень простой вариант.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Далее, полный код 1 простого варианта.
***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:ext_storage/ext_storage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 String _str1 = '';
 String _str2 = '';

 Database _database;
 String _databasesPath = '';
 String _databaseName = '';

 String _tablePerson = '''
  CREATE TABLE Person(
   id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   age INTEGER NOT NULL
  )
 ''';

 List<Person> _ara = [];

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _funDatabaseInit();

 }

 Future<void> _funDatabaseInit() async {
  //путь к расположению базы данных
  _databasesPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
  //имя базы данных
  _databaseName = 'abc.db';
  //соединение пути и имени
  String pathAll = join(_databasesPath, _databaseName);
  //создание или открытие базы
  _database = await openDatabase(pathAll);

  if(_database.isOpen) {
   _funTableCreate(_tablePerson);
   //ГДЕ НУЖНО РАЗМЕСТИТЬ ЭТУ ФУНКЦИЮ ???
   _funGetData();
  }

  setState(() {
   _str1 = '';
   _str2 = '';
   _str1 = '${_database.isOpen}';
   _str2 = _database.path;
  });

 }

 /**/
 Future<void> _funTableCreate(String table) async {
  await _database.execute(table);
 }

 /**/
 Future<void> _funTableInsert(String table, dynamic classModel) async {
  await _database.insert(
   table,
   classModel.toMap(),
   conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace
  );
 }

 /*ФУНКЦИЯ ЗАПОЛНЯЕТ КОЛЛЕКЦИЮ ДАННЫМИ ИЗ ТАБЛИЦЫ*/
 Future<void> _funGetData() async {
  var list = await _database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Person');
  //заполняем коллекцию объектами
  _ara = List<Person>.from( list.map((e) => Person.fromMap(e)) );
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
   children: [
    Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
       OutlineButton(
        onPressed: () {
         setState(() {
          _funTableInsert(
           'Person',
           Person(id: 1, name: 'Ivan', age: 21)
          );
         });
        },
        child: Text(
         'Insert',
         style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          color: Colors.deepPurple
         ),
        ),
       ),
      ],
     ),
    ),
    Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     child: Row(
      children: [
       Text(
        'database is open : $_str1'
       ),
      ],
     ),
    ),
    Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     child: Row(
      children: [
       Text(
        'path : $_str2'
       ),
      ],
     ),
    ),

    Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     child: Row(
      children: [
       Text(
        '${_ara[0].id} ${_ara[0].name} ${_ara[0].age} ',
       ),
      ],
     ),
    ),

   ],
  );
 }

}

class Person {

 //название столбцов таблицы должно совпадать с названием полей
 final int id;
 final String name;
 final int age;

 Person({
  this.id,
  this.name,
  this.age
 });

 //для вставки данных в таблицу
 Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  return {
   'id': id,
   'name': name,
   'age': age,
  };
 }

 //для чтения данных из таблицы
 factory Person.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => Person(
  id: map['id'] as int,
  name: map['name'] as String,
  age: map['age'] as int
 );

}
```

Во втором варианте задача чуть более усложнена. Был создан виджет с условием, если длинна коллекции равно 0, появляется надпись Hello World! , если не равна 0, тогда будет выведены спском данные таблицы. На некоторое время появляется Hello World! , то есть почему-то данные в коллекцию еще не загружены.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем Hello World! исчезает, но при этом ничего не выводится. Данные должны были уже загрузиться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

 Где же расположить функцию? Далее полный код второго варианта
***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:ext_storage/ext_storage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 String _str1 = '';
 String _str2 = '';

 Database _database;
 String _databasesPath = '';
 String _databaseName = '';

 String _tablePerson = '''
  CREATE TABLE Person(
   id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   age INTEGER NOT NULL
  )
 ''';

 List<Person> _ara = [];

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _funDatabaseInit();

 }

 Future<void> _funDatabaseInit() async {
  //путь к расположению базы данных
  _databasesPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
  //имя базы данных
  _databaseName = 'abc.db';
  //соединение пути и имени
  String pathAll = join(_databasesPath, _databaseName);
  //создание или открытие базы
  _database = await openDatabase(pathAll);

  if(_database.isOpen) {
   _funTableCreate(_tablePerson);
   //ГДЕ НУЖНО РАЗМЕСТИТЬ ЭТУ ФУНКЦИЮ ???
   _funGetData();
  }

  setState(() {
   _str1 = '';
   _str2 = '';
   _str1 = '${_database.isOpen}';
   _str2 = _database.path;
  });

 }

 /**/
 Future<void> _funTableCreate(String table) async {
  await _database.execute(table);
 }

 /**/
 Future<void> _funTableInsert(String table, dynamic classModel) async {
  await _database.insert(
   table,
   classModel.toMap(),
   conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace
  );
 }

 /*ФУНКЦИЯ ЗАПОЛНЯЕТ КОЛЛЕКЦИЮ ДАННЫМИ ИЗ ТАБЛИЦЫ*/
 Future<void> _funGetData() async {
  var list = await _database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Person');
  //заполняем коллекцию объектами
  _ara = List<Person>.from( list.map((e) => Person.fromMap(e)) );
 }

 Widget _widgetW() {
  if(_ara.length == 0) {
   return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Row(
     children: [
      Text(
       'Hello World!',
       style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 24.0,
        color: Colors.pink,
       ),
      )
     ],
    ),
   );
  } else {
   return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Row(
     children: [
      ListView.builder(
       itemCount: _ara.length,
       itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(
         '${_ara[index].id} ${_ara[index].name} ${_ara[index].age} ',
        );
       },
      ),
     ],
    ),
   );
  }
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
   children: [
    Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
       OutlineButton(
        onPressed: () {
         setState(() {
          _funTableInsert(
           'Person',
           Person(id: 1, name: 'Ivan', age: 21)
          );
         });
        },
        child: Text(
         'Insert',
         style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          color: Colors.deepPurple
         ),
        ),
       ),
      ],
     ),
    ),
    Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     child: Row(
      children: [
       Text(
        'database is open : $_str1'
       ),
      ],
     ),
    ),
    Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     child: Row(
      children: [
       Text(
        'path : $_str2'
       ),
      ],
     ),
    ),

    _widgetW(),

   ],
  );
 }

}

class Person {

 //название столбцов таблицы должно совпадать с названием полей
 final int id;
 final String name;
 final int age;

 Person({
  this.id,
  this.name,
  this.age
 });

 //для вставки данных в таблицу
 Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  return {
   'id': id,
   'name': name,
   'age': age,
  };
 }

 //для чтения данных из таблицы
 factory Person.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => Person(
  id: map['id'] as int,
  name: map['name'] as String,
  age: map['age'] as int
 );

}
```

Comment: У вас проблема с пониманием как работает асинхронный код.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1013829/261617
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142334/261617
https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вот сделал полный рабочий вариант вашего экрана:
> https://pastebin.com/raw/VNNG99SV.

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
  if(_database.isOpen) {
    await _funTableCreate(_tablePerson);
    await _funGetData();
  }
```

Без ключевого слова `await` возможен кейс, когда `_funGetData();` вызовется до создания таблицы методом `_funTableCreate(_tablePerson);`, что приведет к ошибке.

Также подправьте `build()`, изменив кнопку изменения вставления данных в базу и добавив индикатор загрузки:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_screenLoading) {
      return Center(
        child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
          radius: 24,
        ),
      );
    }
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              OutlineButton(
                onPressed: () =>_funTableInsert('Person', Person(id: 1, name: 'Ivan', age: 21)),
                child: Text(
                  'Insert',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.deepPurple),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text('database is open : $_str1'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text('path : $_str2'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                '${_ara[0].id} ${_ara[0].name} ${_ara[0].age} ',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Подправьте `_funTableInsert()` так, чтобы состояние экрана всегда обновлялось после вставления данных:

```
  Future<void> _funTableInsert(String table, dynamic classModel) async {
    setState(() {
      _screenLoading = true;
    });
    await _database.insert(
        table,
        classModel.toMap(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace
    );
    setState(() {
      _screenLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Добавьте включение индикатора загрузки в метод `_funDatabaseInit()`:

```
  Future<void> _funDatabaseInit() async {
    setState(() {
      _screenLoading = true;
    });
    //путь к расположению базы данных
    _databasesPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    //имя базы данных
    _databaseName = 'abc.db';
    //соединение пути и имени
    String pathAll = join(_databasesPath, _databaseName);
    //создание или открытие базы
    _database = await openDatabase(pathAll);

    if(_database.isOpen) {
      await _funTableCreate(_tablePerson);
      await _funGetData();
    }

    setState(() {
      _str1 = '';
      _str2 = '';
      _str1 = '${_database.isOpen}';
      _str2 = _database.path;
      _screenLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

И в экране создайте переменную `bool _screenLoading;`.

Comment: Уважаемый Maxgmer! Спасибо большое, но пока вывелось Hello World! но уже не исчезает. Данных по прежнему нет. Продолжаю выяснять дальше.

Comment: @Sergey возможно нашел проблему, сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Уважаемый Maxgmer! Спасибо большое, но пока красный экран. Буду разбираться.

Comment: можете дополнить текстом ошибки вопрос пожалуйста? Чтобы понимал куда смотреть дальше) ща разберемся

Comment: Скриншот красного экрана, ошибка такая же.

Comment: @Sergey Дополнил ответ, обновил build(), _funDatabaseInit() и появилась новая переменная _screenLoading.