# Как реализовать поиск элементов, в списке который генерируется при помощи ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

У меня имеется страница которая отображает записи из базы данных в виде Элементов Card. Также для управления состоянием я пользуюсь пакетом Getx. Не знаю как реализовать поиск по этим элементам так чтобы эти элементы отсеивались в режиме реального времени с посимвольным вводом. В моем SearchBar имеется свойство OnChanged, к нему я планировал присоединиться.

Если нужны ещё какие то части моего кода, могу предоставить.

Код моего построителя элементов:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetX<ProductController>(
      init: ProductController(),
      builder: (controller) {
        return FutureBuilder<List<ProductsCombined>>(
          future: controller.productList.value,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    ProductCards(
                  index: index,
                  snapshot: snapshot,
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Код моего контроллера:

```
class ProductController extends GetxController {
  final productList = Future.value(<ProductsCombined>[]).obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchProducts();
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future<List<ProductsCombined>> callDb() async {
    return await DBHelper.db.getProducts();
  }

  void fetchProducts() async {
    productList.value = callDb();
  }
}
```

**EDIT1: Изменил контроллер и некоторые другие места, не уверен насколько верно я сделал в плане оптимизации или ещё чего, но это работает. Привязал контроллер к событию onChanged, и элементы обновляются на экране только после завершения какого либо действия, например скрытие клавиатуры или нажатия кнопки принять, хотелось бы чтобы обновление было сразу при вводе символов**

Измененный код контроллера:

```
class ProductController extends GetxController {
  final productList = Future.value(<ProductsCombined>[]).obs;
  Rx<Future<List<ProductsCombined>>> filterProduct =
      Future.value(<ProductsCombined>[]).obs;

  Future<void> searchChanged(String value) async {
    if (value != null && value.isNotEmpty) {
      List<ProductsCombined> s = await productList.value;
      filterProduct = Future.value(s
              .where((element) => (element.productName
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(value.toLowerCase())))
              .toList())
          .obs;
    } else
      filterProduct = productList;
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchProducts();
    filterProduct = productList;
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future<List<ProductsCombined>> callDb() async {
    return await DBHelper.db.getProducts();
  }

  void fetchProducts() async {
    productList.value = callDb();
  }
}
```

Код в TextField:

```
TextField(
        onChanged: (string) {
          controller.searchChanged(string);
        }
```

И в построителе элементов заменил:

```
return FutureBuilder<List<ProductsCombined>>(
          future: controller.productList.value
```

На:

```
return FutureBuilder<List<ProductsCombined>>(
          future: controller.filterProduct.value
```

[image: Отображение найденных элементов]

Comment: В место `FutureBuilder` используйте `StreamBuilder`, `productList` также должен быть `stream`. Тогда любое обновление потока будет "в режиме реального времени".

Comment: @MiT Я попробовал использовать `StreamBuilder` потом обратно поменял на `FutureBuilder`, странно, но изменений никаких не было, возможно это связано с тем что мой `productList` является `.obs`. Я добавил новую информацию в тему

Comment: Ну потому что с потоком нужно работать как поток, а не как обычная переменная.

Comment: Как ни странно, но `FutureBuilder` в данном случае абсолютно также прослушивает поток как и `StreamBuilder`, просто насколько я знаю `FutureBuilder` должен предоставлять разовый ответ.

Comment: Future это результат асинхронный функции. Там либо ответ (ошибка), либо ожидание. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1013829/261617

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, ознакомлюсь с предоставленной вами темой. Ну а пока вопрос темы все ещё остается открытым.