# Функция в Dart/Flutter

Tags: json, функции, flutter, dart, future

Вот функция:

```
getWeather(city, clientAPI) {
  return (http.get(Uri.parse('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city&appid=${clientAPI}'))).then((value) => value.body);
}
```

Она возвращает *Instance of 'Future'*, а мне нужно строку или словарь, или же JSON. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: await getWeather(); ?

Answer (score 1):

`http.get` это асинхронная функция, следовательно она будет возвращать `Future`. Решить эту проблему можно так:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getWeather(String city, String clientAPI) async {
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city&appid=${clientAPI}'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse =
        convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
   return jsonResponse;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  }

  return body;
}
```

Замете что метод `getWeather` тоже стал асинхронным и возвращает `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>`, чтобы его использовать вам также придётся использовать `async/await`, либо `then`.

---

[Как правильно использовать: Futures, Streams и Async/Await во Flutter?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1013829/261617)